# trying to access matlab from c++ using header

Tags: c++, matlab, gcc, linker, matlab-engine

I'm trying to compile a c++ program which contains Matlab's provided engine header. File  MLP.cpp contains:

```
#include <engine.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

And references the matlab functions highlighted in the errors below. When running:

```
g++ -c MLP.cpp -I/usr/local/matlab/extern/include -L/usr/local/matlab/extern/lib -llibeng -llibmx -lmatlab
g++ MLP.o -o main
```

I get the following errors:

```
MLP.o: In function `MatLabPredictor::MatLabPredictor(char*)': 

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `engOpen'

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `engEvalString'

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `engEvalString'

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `mxCreateDoubleMatrix'

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `mxGetPr'

MLP.o: In function `MatLabPredictor::~MatLabPredictor()':

MLP.cpp:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `engClose'

MLP.o: In function `MatLabPredictor::retrain(double)':

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `engPutVariable'

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `engEvalString'

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `engEvalString'

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `engEvalString'

MLP.o: In function `MatLabPredictor::predict_next_value()':

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `engEvalString'

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `engGetVariable'

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x186): undefined reference to `mxGetData'

MLP.cpp:(.text+0x199): undefined reference to `mxDestroyArray'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have also tried changing the compilation commands to:

```
g++ -c MLP.cpp -I/usr/local/matlab/extern/include -L/usr/local/matlab/bin/glnxa64 -llibeng -llibmx -lmatlab
g++ MLP.o -o main
```

Comment: Try adding "-v" to see if g++ actually links the libraries. The error messages clearly say it does not link libmx and libeng. If you have a "libmx.so" file somewhere, a `-lmx` is usually the proper way to specify it for linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First g++ command you specify is for compiling, you need only `-I` option for that. Give it path to folder where `engine.h` is (`-I$MATLABROOT/extern/include` - Let's say `MATLABROOT` points to root directory of Matlab installation, in this case `/usr/local/matlab`).

Second g++ command is for linking, you need to put -L and -l(s) there. Something like
    `-L$MATLABROOT/bin/glnxa64 -leng -lmx`

So we end up with this sequence:

`g++ -c MLP.cpp -I$MATLABROOT/extern/include`

`g++ MLP.o -o main -L$MATLABROOT/bin/glnxa64 -leng -lmx`

For getting the same, but in a single line:

`g++ MLP.c -o main -I$MATLABROOT/extern/include -L$MATLABROOT/bin/glnxa64 -leng -lmx`

Note:  `libeng.so` and `libmx.so` must be reachable when you want to run this executable, so extend `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `PATH` with folder: `$MATLABROOT/bin/glnxa64` before attempting to run `main`.

Answer (score 0):

On 64-bit Linux, you probably want change the lib path to:

> ${MATLABROOT}/extern/lib/glnxa64

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to compile engine programs is to use the `mex` command along with the supplied options file `engopts.sh`:

```
>> engopts = fullfile(matlabroot,'bin','engopts.sh');
>> mex('-f',engopts, 'MLP.cpp')
```

If you want you could run the above with the verbose flag `mex -v ...`, and copy the generated compilation and linking flags into your own build system.

(I believe the problem is that you should drop the `lib` part from the library names: `g++ file.cpp -I${MROOT}/extern/include -L${MROOT}/extern/lib/${ARCH} -leng -lmx`)

Note: dont forget to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that your program is able to find the required MATLAB shared libraries when run.

See [these](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-with-the-mex-command.html) [pages](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101334) for more info.

Comment: It cannot find -leng and -lmx ... I'm not sure about LD_LIBRARY_PATH ... is it a directory for leng and lmx?

Comment: @user2989812 There should be a glnxa64 subdirectory (${ARCH} in Amro's answer) in extern/lib.  Be sure you are pointing there with -L. Can you confirm this? Worry about the runtime libraries (LD_LIBRARY_PATH) after you have a successful link.

Comment: @user2989812: did you use the `engopts` file as I described? `mex` will know how to compile engine programs, you wont have have to worry about the compilation/linking process.. Just make sure to run `mex -setup` at least once before

Comment: g++ MLP.cpp -I/usr/local/matlab/extern/include -L/usr/local/matlab/extern/lib/glnxa64 -leng -lmx
  :          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -leng
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmx
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status      This the error I'm getting doing the intructions